# PDO returning only one result, expected way more

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

To begin, maybe I'm doing it wrong so be kind ;)

I have to generate my SQL request by looping on an array :

```
$sql = "SELECT data_mt_poids.Fap87, Type, Part, Info, Fap87_libcourt 
        FROM data_mt_poids 
            INNER JOIN lib_fap87 ON data_mt_poids.Fap87 = lib_fap87.Fap87   
        WHERE ";
$i = 1;

foreach($liste_territoire as $territoire)
{
    foreach($fap_array as $fap)
    {
        $sql .= "data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR ";
    }
}

$sql = substr($sql, 0, - 3);

$results = null;
try
{
    $conn = Db::getInstance();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $i = 1;
    foreach($liste_territoire as $territoire)
    {
        foreach($fap_array as $fap)
        {
            $requested_zefap = $territoire.'-'.$fap;
            $stmt->bindParam($i, $requested_zefap);
            ++$i;
        }
    }

    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die("Error ".$e->getCode()." : ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

There are 4 territoire and 2 F.A.P.

I had logged the SQL request, it is OK, in fact everything seems fine to me :/

This return only the last possible result (the last $territoire-$fap couple)

And this happened only when I use prepared query :/

Here's a debugDumpParams() :

```
SQL: [361] SELECT data_mt_poids.Fap87, Type, Part, Info, Fap87_libcourt FROM data_mt_poids INNER JOIN lib_fap87 ON data_mt_poids.Fap87 = lib_fap87.Fap87 WHERE data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? OR data_mt_poids.ZEFAP = ? 
Params:  8
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #2:
paramno=2
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #3:
paramno=3
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #4:
paramno=4
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #5:
paramno=5
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #6:
paramno=6
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #7:
paramno=7
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

Thank in advance for your help ;)

Comment: You `print_r` the `$results` and it only has 1 row or how are you using that? You also could simplify the binding a bit. I'd do it this way, https://3v4l.org/qC0fl (ignore the errors, just being used as a clipboard).

Comment: this is happening because you only execute the query after the two foreach loops have run, at which point the bound parameter is set to the last value in the inner foreach loop

Comment: @chris85 Yes, I was thinking about doing it that way, I deleted my change when I detect the bug ^^" I'm using the result to generate a chart with Highcharts (it's working by the way ^^)

Comment: try using bindValue instead of bindParam

Comment: @DJC I had edited my post with a $stmt->debugDumpParams() so you can see the number of iteration and the number of binded var (it seems fine to me :/) I'll try using bindValue and keep you updated ;)

Comment: Ok, using bindValue do the trick, I'll will investigate to understand why x)
Thanks a lot you two ;)

Comment: @Syulwen I've explained why in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bindValue() instead of bindParam().

This is because bindParam() binds the variable as a reference, and will only be evaluated when execute() is called - see PHP Manual for [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)